# REST API to fetch List/LIbrary URL's from subsites

Tags: 2013, javascript, office-365, rest

I am working on a requirement to display all sub sites and list/Libraries inside sub site using REST. I am able to fetch Sub sites and List/Libraries but i am not able to fetch List/Library Url's. Can anyone please help me in fetching List URL's using REST API.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this URL : `http://rootsite/_api/Web/webs?$expand=Lists/RootFolder&$select=Lists/RootFolder/ServerRelativeURL`. This will return the subwebs along with the lists property expanded for each subweb.  The `Lists` property will return all the lists and libraries associated with the subsite.

Comment: Yeah your's better. No need to iterate sub webs.

Answer (score 9):

Try this one:

```
/_api/Web/Lists?$select=Title,RootFolder/ServerRelativeUrl&$expand=RootFolder
```

Then iterate all results and select `list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl`.

Comment: A bit earlier :)

Comment: If you're in a modern enough environment, JavaScript's map() function can help with the iteration part: let listInfos = items.map((item: any) => { return { title: item.Title, url: item.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl }; });